# js exception position

Tags: javascript, debugging, exception

For the JavaScript code like this:

```
try {
    MyJob.process();
} catch(e) {
    console.log("Exception occur!");
}
```

I run the code in Chrome or FireFox, When the exception happens, the line number of "Exception occur!" will be shown in console, but the original exception in MyJob won't be there. Is there any solution that show the original position where the exception happens and keep the try-catch that I write here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.onerror = function ( msg, url, num ) {
   alert ( "Error: " + msg + "\nURL: " + url + "\nLine: " + num );
   return true;
};
```

This will show most of the errors.

In the catch block add:

```
catch(e) {
    console.log( e.name + ": " + e.message );
}
```

More about the error handling at [JavaScriptkit](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/trycatch2.shtml)

If the try/catch block is inside a function you could take advantage of the `arguments.callee` [<sup>mdn</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee) [<sup>msdn</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/334e1zza%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

```
function foo() {
    try {
        someFunction();
    }
    catch (e) {
        var f = arguments.callee.toString().substr ( "function ".length);
        f = f.substr(0, f.indexOf('('));
        alert ( "Error type : " + e.name + "\nError : " + e.message + "\nIn function : " + f );
    }
}
```

Result will be:

```
Error type : ReferenceError
Error : someFunction is not defined
In function : foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Temporary comment out the `try` and `catch`, then step through with the Chrome (or Firefox) JavaScript debugging tools.

```
//try {
    MyJob.process();
/*} catch(e) {
    console.log("Exception occur!");
}*/
```

After identifying the issue, remove the comments to restore the original error handling.